# Trouble with VCA as signal amplitude control

Tags: operational-amplifier, multiplier, amplitude, volume, voltage-controlled-amplifier

I designed (and tested) the classic analog multiplier composed with operational amplifiers. However, the voltage resulting from the operation did not correspond to the product of the input voltages.

[image: Analog multiplier as VCA]

The case is all books I have at hand neither specify a voltage range for the inputs nor a resistor value for it to work. Do I have to reduce voltage on the inputs? Is the generic 10k resistor fine for this purpose?

As an alternative, I tried to build a differential amplifier out of transistors for the same purpose, but ended with a kill ratio of 3 over 4 transistors used.

I would like to use the circuit as tone amplitude modulator, so in reality I am seeking for a voltage-controlled attenuator.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What power supply did you provide?

Comment: @user_1818839 Sorry, I forgot to mention I use +/- 12V from a standard ATX PSU.

Comment: Next step then would be to test each stage separately. How close is R1/Q1 output to log(Vin)? and so on. Ditto, is U2a output the (negated) sum of its two inputs? etc.

Comment: @user_1818839 The circuit has been cut stage-wise and isolated in smaller boards, then tested individually. The adder was working fine, but some log amplifiers delivered the full supply voltage; they were later found to have broken 4558.

Comment: that's what debugging takes! well done.

Comment: How does the input not match the output? There are many other details needed to do troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have the general configuration correct log amplifiers such as the first stage are usually unstable without compensation. They also tend to have low bandwidth and they only work with unipolar signals. In general they are not useful for periodic signals as you have, even when maintained as unipolar.

The anti-log transistor is backwards (it may work in reverse but not well). You typically also need temperature compensation.

As others have said, test each section separately, measure the intermediate voltages and view on a scope to check for oscillation.

[Theory and Application of Log Amplifiers](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa575b/snoa575b.pdf)

Linear multiplication is not an easy function to create but you are likely to have better success with the approach used in ICs such as the SA571 ([datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/sa571-d.pdf)).

Comment: Well, the transistor in the schematics was a copy error - namely I copied it manually without further revising. The real circuit has the transistor placed with the appropiate orientation. Regarding the oscillation... well no need to bring the oscilloscope as I have already observed it. This multiplier doesn't seem much stable, I'll consider the alternate way you are proposing.